# Win32 cannot resume thread that suspend it self

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

In Win32 I want to suspend a thread using `Suspend(GetCurrentThread());` but I find I cannot resume it using `ResumeThread(suspend thread handle);` But I find nothing happened.

Here it's my code.

```c
HANDLE C;
DWORD WINAPI A (LPVOID in)
{
    C = GetCurrentThread();
    cout << "1";
    SuspendThread (C);
    cout << "4";
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI B (LPVOID in)
{
    Sleep (200);
    cout << "2";
    ResumeThread (C);
    cout << "3";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    CreateThread (NULL, 0, A, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CreateThread (NULL, 0, B, NULL, 0, NULL);
    Sleep (INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

And all I get on screen is `123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible right now that when `B` calls `ResumeThread`, the variable `C` contains an uninitialized value.

However, the current reason why your code does not work is that `GetCurrentThread` only returns a pseudo-thread handle, a value interpreted to mean the current thread handle. To get the real one which can be used from other threads, you can take the one from the return of the first `CreateThread` call or convert the pseudo-handle with `DuplicateHandle`.

**Edit**: Using method 1:

```
HANDLE C;
DWORD WINAPI A (LPVOID in)
{
    cout << "1";
    SuspendThread (C);
    cout << "4";
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI B (LPVOID in)
{
    Sleep (200);
    cout << "2";
    ResumeThread ((HANDLE)in);
    cout << "3";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    C = CreateThread (NULL, 0, A, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CreateThread (NULL, 0, B, (LPVOID)C, 0, NULL);
    Sleep (INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

In fact there is another problem with your code which is that handles returned from `CreateThread` are being ignored when they should be closed. Also there is a lack of error checking but I have assumed you've omitted that for brevity.

You should also note that, depending on the timing of the context switch it is actually possible for the above code to output:

> 1243

Using method 2:

```
HANDLE C = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI A (LPVOID in)
{
    C = GetCurrentThread();
    DuplicateHandle( GetCurrentProcess(), C, GetCurrentProcess(), &C, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS );
    cout << "1";
    SuspendThread (C);
    cout << "4";
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI B (LPVOID in)
{
    Sleep (200);
    cout << "2";

    while( C == NULL ) {
      Sleep(100);
    }
    ResumeThread(C);
    cout << "3";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    CreateThread (NULL, 0, A, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CreateThread (NULL, 0, B, NULL, 0, NULL);
    Sleep (INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in fact I'm sure that C is initialized using Debug.

Comment: update: I recheck its value by using your way. And I found that `GetCurrentThread` do have returned value but it's wrong.But Why? and how I can get the right value if I cannot use `CreateThread`